# Symfony 4, Postgres - `Invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "utf8mb4"` on running doctrine command

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, symfony4

**The Problem**

I have a fresh setup of `postgres 10.5` and `symfony 4` application running on `php 7.1`. But when I try running migration. I keep getting the following `Invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "utf8mb4"` error.
[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

1. On `.env` file by modify DSN to correct value based on the your settings for eg. mine was`DATABASE_URL="pgsql://postgres:password@db:5432/a_db"`.
2. Create an entity (Any would do) using `php bin/console make:entity`
3. Make Migration file `php bin/console make:migration`

**Expected Result**

I should have received `Success` message.

**So my Question is**

What did I miss here as I have followed the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So my actual client config in the postgres is `utf8` not `utf8mb4`. It seems symfony does not automatically detects the version and database for us.

`Symfony 4` has left the standard `utf8mb4` for `MYSQL` in the config file `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`. This configuration file should not be forgotten to change based on these [allowed configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#reference-dbal-configuration). So the problem was fixed when I changed the value

**from**

`dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

**to**

`dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_postgresql'
    server_version: '10.5'
    charset: utf8
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8
        collate: utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Who ever posted negative voting.,It would be helpful if you post your comment. Why did my answer deserves vote instead of silently running away.

Comment: Can't see any reason for the downvotes, so I'm giving you upvotes ;-) BTW: You can append the charset to `DATABASE_URL` inside `.env` like this: `DATABASE_URL="pgsql://postgres:password@db:5432/a_db?charset=UTF-8` Looks like this isn't really documented anywhere, so I opened this https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/10410

Comment: I believe the `default_table_options` would be best to be removed so that the database defaults control those settings, instead of Doctrine. However `utf8_unicode_ci` is exclusive to MySQL and not available for PostgreSQL which uses `en_US.UTF-8` as in the [Doctrine DBAL test](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.7/tests/Doctrine/Tests/DBAL/Platforms/PostgreSQL91PlatformTest.php)

Answer (score 4):

For me it helped to add the encoding to the Database URL, like this:

`postgres://api-platform:!ChangeMe!@db/api?charset=UTF-8`

Though this problem only occurred in `APP_ENV=prod`.